# custom id not showing up in paypal webhook

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

So I'm trying to put in a custom id (order id) in my paypal order so it get's returned to me in my paypal webhook but I cannot find it in my webhook.
This is my order code.

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
        "intent":"sale",
        "payer":{
            "payment_method":"paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls":{
            "return_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/success",
            "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/cancel"
        },
        "transactions":[{
            "item_list":{
                "items":items
            },
            "amount":{
                "total":price,
                "currency":"EUR"
            },
            "description":"This is the payment transaction description.",
            "custom_id": order_data["products"][0]['order']
        }]
    })
    if payment.create():
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', "url": payment.links[1].href})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

Everything in this code works except for the custom id which i dont get back in my webhook. Am I missing something.

Extra note. Just tried this.

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
        "intent":"sale",
        "payer":{
            "payment_method":"paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls":{
            "return_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/success",
            "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/cancel"
        },
        "transactions":[{
            "item_list":{
                "items":items
            },
            "amount":{
                "total":price,
                "currency":"EUR"
            },
            "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
        }],
        "custom_id": order_data["products"][0]['order']
    })
    if payment.create():
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', "url": payment.links[1].href})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

I moved the custom id out of the `transactions` key, it was an oversight of me but now my payment does not get created in the browser I receive `{status: error}` instead of the payment url of paypal. All help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing all PayPal REST SDKs are deprecated and should not be used for new integrations. Furthermore, the v1/payments API is deprecated and should not be used for anything new.

Instead, see the current standard integration guide at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ . Its 2 sample routes that return JSON are shown in node.js for example purposes but can of course be implemented with any backend environment, including Python/Django.

Comment: Is it considered unsafe to use this deprecated rest sdk?

Comment: It is obsolete and not maintained